# Ng-repeat priority

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: "<div></div>",
        link: function(scope, elem) {

            scope.list  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            $compile("<div my-list></div>")(scope, function(clone) {
                // Why the ng-repeat isn't compiled yet?
                alert(clone[0].outerHTML);
                elem.html(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive("myList", function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: "<ul><li ng-repeat=\"item in list\">{{item}}</li></ul>"
    };
});
```

`<div my-directive></div>`

Can someone tell me why my `<li>'s` are not at my `alert`?

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFigueiredoo/jNceZ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I'm going to add a bit more to @dawuut's answer.

Wrapping the `alert` in a `$timeout` with a '0' cooldown will work because timeouts are not fired until the end of the angular `$digest` cycle.

So, when you are first calling `alert` in the parent directive, the children have not been compiled yet (they all have their own scope).

Answer (score 4):

**[Here is your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNceZ/5/)**

It's working using the $timeout directive ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)) with a '0' cooldown. Sounds a bit tricky but...

So, inject **$timeout** in your controller, then in your callback :

```
$timeout(function () {
    alert(clone[0].outerHTML);
}, 0);
```

Comment: I think the OP was interested in "Why" this is the behaviour.  So, why would adding a `$timeout` make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your task of compiling `<div my-list></div>` is computed simultanously with the generation of the `li`s in the subdirective.

That would explain why your `alert` happens before the complete generation of `li` by `ng-repeater`.

Thus, a `$timeout` is useful in order to linearize both tasks.

The explanation of why is here: [Why timeout(0) is sometimes necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/985949)